# The construction of solution of Newton-Pepys problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm studying probability by the book "introduction to probability" of Joseph K. I saw the solution of Newton-Pepys problem, but i'm struggling to understand why it chooses ${12\choose 1}5^{11}$ and not ${12\choose 1}6^{11}$ to calculate the probability of event B.

The Newton-Pepys problem is formulated as follows:

Isaac Newton was consulted about
the following problem by Samuel Pepys, who wanted the information for gambling
purposes. Which of the following events has the highest probability?

A: At least one 6 appears when 6 fair dice are rolled.

B: At least two 6’s appear when 12 fair dice are rolled.

C: At least three 6’s appear when 18 fair dice are rolled

solution:
The solution of A is pretty simple, i have $6^6$ elements in my sample space and $5^6$ forms of the rolled dice is not a six, so, the probability is:
$P(A) = 1 - \frac{5^6}{6^6}.$

To B, the solution is 
$P(B) = 1 - \dfrac{5^{12} + {12\choose 1}5^{11} }{6^{12}},$

i didnt understood why is ${12\choose 1}5^{11}$ and not ${12\choose 1}6^{11}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the probability of it not being a six so there are 5 choices.